# Is there an equivalent of the mongo addToSet command in rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb

Say I have a users table with an embedded followers array property.

```
{
  "followers": [
    "bar"
   ] ,
  "name":  "foo" ,
}
```

In rethinkDb, what's the best way to add a username to that followers property.  i.e. add a follower to a user.

In mongodb I would use the addToSet command to add a unique value to the embedded array.  Should I use the merge command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RethinkDB has a `setInsert` command.  You can write `table.get(ID).update({followers: r.row('followers').setInsert(FOLLOWER)})`.

Comment: and to remove, should I use `difference` or `setDifference`?  It seems like in this case it wouldn't make a difference either way?  What happens with the difference function if it's done on a non unique set?  Does it just remove the first one or all instances of that value?

Comment: If you're calling them on an array that's already a set, yeah, they should do the same thing.  If you don't, then `difference` will remove all instances of the values in the righthand array, it's equivalent to `arr1.filter(function(row) { return arr2.contains(row).not(); })`.